# How to share a spanable string using intent to other apps without losing its fonts style?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an app and i want to send text which has custom font style to other text using intent. So how can I do this. Thanks.

Comment: Grats for you.. "working on app". Keep up the good work and if you need help post some code you're working on. For now we're not your mechanical turk. Enjoy put some labor in it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do that, you should set a typeface for the destination textview.
you can send name of your custom font as an extra with the intent.
I also recommend use [this library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to change font of the whole project in a simple way.